# while running mongod.exe command in terminal getting below error, i have added C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin to environment variable

Tags: mongodb

mongod.exe : The term 'mongod.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- mongod.exe
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (mongod.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: mongod.exe commant is woring when run in the terminal which is open in C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin path

Comment: have you specified the path in the title into PATH env variable? If so, I vote that it's not correct path

Comment: *but* make sure that you restarted powershell after PATH is updated, otherwise the data you specified will be invisible

Comment: thank you, it is woring now after restarting the powershell and